# Bootstrap4 input validation adding 'invalid-feedback' to 'form-group'

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap v4.0.0  validation on my form group. For example, on a change password form, the user inputs

1. Old Password
2. New Password
3. New Password (confirm)

If the new passwords aren't matching, then the validation turns the box red and shows and error message.

My code is working locally showing the validation messages, but in production, the invalid fields are disappearing. Here's what's happening:

Locally on submit, if the old password were invalid, the div would look like the following:

```
<div id="div_id_oldpassword" class="form-group">
```

In production on submit, if the old password were invalid, the div would look like the following:

```
<div id="div_id_oldpassword" class="form-group invalid-feedback">
```

If I remove the `invalid-feedback` class from form-group, the form looks as it should, but with it there, the form has property `display: none`.

I'm not sure why this class is being added here, especially since I'm not making any changes from my code (or bootstrap css file) from local -> production.

What might be causing these differences? How can I stop bootstrap from adding this class here? I can fix it by using JS, but is there another solution I'm missing?

**JS Solution**

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('.form-group').removeClass('invalid-feedback');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect answer, but I have found this to be the best solution. Places this after your bootstrap.css link to overwrite some of the changes.

```
/* Invalid feedback fix */
.invalid-feedback {
   display: inherit !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   margin-top: inherit !important;
   font-size: 13px !important;
   color: #e74a3b !important;
}
.invalid-feedback label:first-child {
   font-size: 16px !important;
}
```